# Extract list from tuples and transpose in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, transpose

I have the dataframe given below. I want to extract the first list from the tuples list and transpose the the list which is extracted to columns.

```
data = {'Document_No':[0.0,1.0], 'list_of_topics': [
([(0, 0.14572892),
  (1, 0.014889247),
  (11, 0.44593897)],
 [(4, [0]), (5, [4]), (6, [11]), (7, [11]), (8, [11, 4]), (9, [11, 4])],
 [(4, [(0, 0.9999998)]),
  (7, [(11, 0.9999998)]),
  (9, [(4, 0.05520946), (11, 0.93936676)])]),
([(0, 0.2453892),
  (11, 0.78657897)],
 [(4, [0]), (5, [4]), (6, [11]), (7, [11]), (8, [11, 4]), (9, [11, 4])],
 [(4, [(0, 0.9999998)]),
  (7, [(11, 0.9999998)]),
  (9, [(4, 0.05520946), (11, 0.93936676)])])
]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

desired result:

```
  Document_No     0            1                 11
0          0.0  0.14572892  0.014889247     0.44593897
1          1.0  0.2453892   0               0.78657897
```

My solution:

```
pd.DataFrame([[j[0] for j in i] for i in df['list_of_topics']], index=df['Document_No']).transpose()
Out[245]: 
Document_No                    0.0                    1.0
0                  (0, 0.14572892)        (0, 0.14572892)
1                         (4, [0])               (4, [0])
2            (4, [(0, 0.9999998)])  (4, [(0, 0.9999998)])
```

Not getting the desired result. Can anyone help me out in finding where I am doing wrong.

Comment: @pygo, it's already mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick your requrired tuples in column and use regular expressions to extract the data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.list_of_topics[0])
for tup in df.list_of_topics[1:]:
    df1 = df1.merge(pd.DataFrame.from_records(tup),on=0,how='outer')

df1.set_index(0,inplace=True)
df1.T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Out:

```
            0   1   11
0   0.145729    0.014889    0.445939
1   0.245389    NaN     0.786579
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is it necessary to convert it into string? Because I want to keep it as float.

Comment: You can convert back to float , i just made changes

Comment: One more quick question, is it mandatory to pass column name in 3rd line of code? Because in my real problem, that number keeps on changing for example we have column 0,1,2 in some list but in some we have only 0,2 column(1 is not there, so I need that column should still be there but value should be 0).